# Cant pip install anything

Tags: python

I am new to python,after downloading it I tried to download a few packages but they all give a long error:

```
pip install pandas

Collecting pandas
  Using cached pandas-1.1.3.tar.gz (5.2 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\turqay\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' 'c:\users\turqay\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\Turqay\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-a8k3gf7x\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel 'Cython>=0.29.21,<3' 'numpy==1.15.4; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.15.4; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version>='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version>='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"''
       cwd: None
  Complete output (326 lines):
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.6" and platform_system != "AIX"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.7" and platform_system != "AIX"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.6" and platform_system == "AIX"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.7" and platform_system == "AIX"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version >= "3.8" and platform_system == "AIX"' don't match your environment
  Collecting setuptools
    Using cached setuptools-50.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (785 kB)
  Collecting wheel
    Using cached wheel-0.35.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (33 kB)
  Collecting Cython<3,>=0.29.21
    Using cached Cython-0.29.21-py2.py3-none-any.whl (974 kB)
  Collecting numpy==1.17.3
    Using cached numpy-1.17.3.zip (6.4 MB)
  Using legacy 'setup.py install' for numpy, since package 'wheel' is not installed.     
  Installing collected packages: setuptools, wheel, Cython, numpy
      Running setup.py install for numpy: started
      Running setup.py install for numpy: finished with status 'error'
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: 'c:\users\turqay\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Turqay\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-67q7i3xi\\numpy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Turqay\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-67q7i3xi\\numpy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Turqay\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-f_ldxfuf\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --prefix 'C:\Users\Turqay\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-a8k3gf7x\overlay' --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Turqay\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-a8k3gf7x\overlay\Include\numpy'
           cwd: C:\Users\Turqay\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-67q7i3xi\numpy\
      Complete output (303 lines):
      Running from numpy source directory.

      Note: if you need reliable uninstall behavior, then install
      with pip instead of using `setup.py install`:

        - `pip install .`       (from a git repo or downloaded source
                                 release)
        - `pip install numpy`   (last NumPy release on PyPi)


      blas_opt_info:
      blas_mkl_info:
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries mkl_rt not found in ['c:\\users\\turqay\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\turqay\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      blis_info:
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries blis not found in ['c:\\users\\turqay\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\turqay\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
        NOT AVAILABLE
```

and it keeps going with not available or sometimes with `pg_config executable not found` i am on python 3.9 and windows 10, i tried some other stack overflow questions solutions but they all were for windows.

Edit: I installed test pip and networkx, the errors are for pandas and matplotlib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try installing a lower version of Python such as Python 3.8 or Python 3.7?

If you still want to move forward with Python 3.9 you need to install two visual studio dist packages:

1. Download Visual C++ Build Tools installer and install it from here: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691126&fixForIE=.exe
2. Go to this link and download the setup and install Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015: https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=48145

Try to install the required packages once again.

Comment: is python 3.9 the problem?

Comment: pandas 1.1.3  supports Python 3.9 but it requires NumPy to run. But currently the latest version of NumPy still in testing mode for Python 3.9. If you downgrade the python version it will be easier.